# Constantly getting this error on Chrome "Resolving Host”

Tags: windows, networking, google-chrome, dns

I have been getting this error constantly my desktop and laptop and the way I do is to run the below batch file but after a day or so its come back again and I'm looking for a more permanent fix then running this batch file every day... I'm sick with this error and I have scan the web but I don't find anything else other than asking to flush the dns which I'm doing.

Is that anything to do with Router ?

Anybody has any solution this problem?

```
@Echo on
pushd\windows\system32\drivers\etc
attrib -h -s -r hosts
echo 127.0.0.1 localhost>HOSTS
attrib +r +h +s hosts
popd
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /flushdns
netsh winsock reset all
netsh int ip reset all
shutdown -r -t 1
del %0
```

Right click the .bat file and choose to Run as Administrator.

Comment: This will undoubtedly be a DNS problem... is your router a modem/router combo provided by your ISP? Additionally, check your Windows networking settings to make sure your LAN adapter is receiving an IP and DNS automatically (this will be from your router). Finally, try factory resetting your modem/router (if your ISP is any good then they'll have preset the details in firmware so a factory reset will still get your internet working).

Comment: Thanks, my modem/router is not provided by my ISP, i thought of doing factory resetting my modem/router but if I do that then I have to call my ISP to update my modem/router in their list? I'm not a networking person but looks like the last resort is to do factory reset.

Comment: You could log in to your modem/router and backup the configuration before doing a factory reset - this should at least give you something to try to rule out your modem/router being the culprit... You could even make a simple change in your modem/router to use external DNS addresses (such as Google's) rather than those provided by your ISP... some ISP DNS servers can be poor performing...

Comment: if i take the backup the config and reset and modem/router then do i need to call my ISP? I'm not sure if its required

Comment: change the google dns address in the router or the computer?

Comment: If you backup your router's current setup then (if the reset causes your Internet to no longer work) you can re-load the backup and you'll be back to square one.

Comment: yes i do have google dns on tcp/ipv4 (8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4) still get the resolving host error

Comment: You can try both... it's easier to set the router DNS because all your LAn clients will get these and make life easier.

Comment: If you keep getting major problems you may want to consider refreshing your Windows install as you shouldn't be getting problems like this to require such steps as you currently are (the script you have)...

Comment: I doubt that it has anything to do with windows OS and when you say refresh your windows, you mean re-install ?

Comment: Have you tried an alternative modem/router? I would try backing up the router config and factory resetting it. Ultimately, if you are unsure as to steps that may require the assistance of your ISP then are you going to be capable of overcoming any issues if you mess with any router settings? It seems that one thing that may fix your problem you're not entirely sure how to recover from if things go wrong... E.g. I know that if I mess up any settings on MY own modem/router that I know how to recover from it/backed up my config so it doesn't worry me.

Comment: so I'm using `Netgear c6300`, the worst case scenario i have to reset to factory but before that do you think I should try any other commands? and i went to advanced tab-->administration-->backup settings so I did able to take the backup.